# GDI+ - References to Shapes

Tags: python, .net, graphics, tkinter, gdi+

In python, when drawing with `tkinter` module, you can retain a reference to a shape and then manipulate that shape using the reference.

Is there anything similar in .NET using GDI+? What are some workarounds?

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
id = canvas.create_polygon(10, 10, 30, 60, 60, 10, fill='blue') # returns reference
count = 0
def movetriangle(event):
        canvas.move(id, 5, 3)
        global count
        if count == 0:
                canvas.itemconfig(id, fill='red')
                count = 1
        elif count == 1:
                canvas.itemconfig(id, fill='green')
                count = 2
        else:
                canvas.itemconfig(id, fill='blue')
                count = 0
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Return>', movetriangle)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDI+ is a rasterizer (executes draw commands by rasterizing them to a bitmap). What you are looking for is a (persistent) vector graphics library. The best .NET match is probably [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation).

For example, the [Polygon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polygon(v=vs.110).aspx) class looks like what you are looking for.

[SVG](http://svg.codeplex.com/) is also widely used across platforms.

Comment: It is not possible with Winforms then?

Comment: Yes it is, but you need a third party library. Look at the SVG link in my answer for example, but there are others.

Comment: Though I would think it would be easier to do in WPF, and you will have better performance. You can interop between Winford's and WPF, look at WindowsFormsHost.